# Add Cloud SQL connection to underlying Cloud Run when deploying cloudfunctions2

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-functions

My Cloud Function code connects to Cloud SQL through sqlalchemy to perform SQL operations.
I needed to upgrade to Cloud Function 2nd Gen. For this, I need to wait for the underlying Cloud Run service to be created during the initial deployment. Then manually add Cloud SQL connection in Cloud Run configuration for the Cloud Function to work.

Terraform code for cloudfunction2:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  name        = "${var.pipeline_name}-${var.environment}" 
  location    = var.region
  description = "Connect to Cloud SQL"
  project     = var.project_name
  build_config {
    runtime     = "python38"
    entry_point = "establish_connection" # Set the entry point
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.export_bucket.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.cloud_function_src.name
      }
    }
  }

  service_config {
    max_instance_count            = 1
    available_memory              = "1Gi"
    timeout_seconds               = 3600
    service_account_email         = var.service_account
    vpc_connector_egress_settings = "ALL_TRAFFIC"
    vpc_connector                 = "projects/${nw_project}/locations/us-east1/connectors/use1-01-${var.environment}"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to add the Cloud SQL connection to the underlying Cloud Run in Terraform?

Comment: Could you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018718/terraform-google-cloud-run-add-cloud-sql-connection) if it is similar with your issue?